# pluck not found on Rx.observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm playing around with https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS trying to run through their example using Typescript and Angular 2. When I compile the code it complains that "Property 'pluck' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'". I can't figure out why pluck is not available. Did it get removed for rxjs 5?

Using:

angular 2.0.0-beta.0
rxjs  5.0.0-beta.0

Code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {Title} from '../providers/title';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  directives: [...FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [Title],
  pipes: [],
  styles: [require('./home.css')],
  template: require('./home.html')
})
export class Home {
  wikisearch: any = {};

  // TypeScript public modifiers
  constructor(public title: Title, public http: Http) {
    var input = document.getElementById('wikisearch');

    /* Only get the value from each key up */
    var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
      .pluck('target', 'value')
      .filter((text) => text.length > 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should have something like `Observable.fromEvent<TYPE[]>()` where `TYPE` is the type of items you get from that function.

Comment: A quick solution would be `Observable.fromEvent<any[]>(...)`

Comment: @Louy that would not help. It is not a typescript problem. The problem is that pluck is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular 2 uses RxJS 5 (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS), which is a complete rewrite of the current version (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). RxJS 5 is still in beta. Some operators from RxJS 4 are not yet available in RxJS 5. This is the case for `pluck`. I recommend you take a look at [RxJS 5 documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/) and also the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) as there are some API differences between these two versions.

For this particular example, you can easily replace the `pluck` operator by using `map` instead:

```
var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
    .map((target) => target.value)
    .filter((text) => text.length > 2);
```

---

**Update:** `pluck` is [now available](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/pull/1167) in RxJS 5 since version [5.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/tree/5.0.0-beta.1).

Comment: Thanks @luisgabriel this is the same conclusion I came to. The problem I was having was that I was looking at the old documentation and could not find the docs for the beta.